# Asciidoc table for counter values and text references

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I am creating an asciidoc as described below:

```
Start of document 

* R{counter:recom}: sentence1 
...
* R{counter:recom}: sentence2
...
* R{counter:recom}: sentence3

End
```

Note: The `R{counter:recom}` from the asciidoc will be displayed as `R1 R2 R3` in the resulting document.

I need to create a table at the start of the document which will refer the counters and text form the doc as described below:

```
Start of document 

|Ref#|text from the document
|R1|sentence1
|R2|sentence2
|R3|sentence3

throughout the doc: 

* R{counter:recom}: sentence1
...
* R{counter:recom}: sentence2
...
* R{counter:recom}: sentence3

End
```

Now, there are 2 unknown things here:

1. How do I refer the counter and sentence part from the asciidoc `R1 sentence1` in the table together or separately so that, if I change it in the doc it will be changed in the table?
2. How do I refer the counter values in the table so that they work as links to the actual counter value `R1` in the doc?

Not sure there is a readymade construct to achieve this and I haven't figured out how can I achieve it using an `anchor` or `include` statement.

Comment: I think this may be beyond the capabilities of AsciiDoc. Even if you can track a coordinated pair of counters, you can't express them as part of a later attribute evaluation. This would seem to be a case for pre-generating a list of `R<n>` and `sentence<n>` attributes up front and ingesting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is an experiment with attributes. It fulfills the following requirements:

- if you change the sentence in the attribute, it will be changed in both the table and the doc
- the table and the doc will contain the same number
- the table to the item in the document

```
:ref-a: R{counter:recom}
:sen-a: sentence1

:ref-b: R{counter:recom}
:sen-b: sentence2

:ref-c: R{counter:recom}
:sen-c: sentence3

|===
|Ref#|text from the document
|<<link-a>>|{sen-a}
|<<link-b>>|{sen-b}
|<<link-c>>|{sen-c}
|===

throughout the doc:

* [[link-a,{ref-a}]]{ref-a}: {sen-a}
...
* [[link-b,{ref-b}]]{ref-b}: {sen-b}
...
* [[link-c,{ref-c}]]{ref-c}: {sen-c}
...
```

rendering this with either

```
Asciidoctor 2.0.10 [https://asciidoctor.org]
Runtime Environment (jruby 9.2.7.0 (2.5.3) 2019-04-09 8a269e3 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.161-b12 on 1.8.0_161-b12 +jit [mswin32-x86_64]) (lc:CP850 fs:Windows-1252 in:CP850 ex:CP850)
```

or

```
Asciidoctor PDF 1.5.0.beta.1 using Asciidoctor 2.0.10 [https://asciidoctor.org]
Runtime Environment (jruby 9.2.7.0 (2.5.3) 2019-04-09 8a269e3 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.161-b12 on 1.8.0_161-b12 +jit [mswin32-x86_64]) (lc:CP850 fs:Windows-1252 in:CP850 ex:CP850)
```

displays

[image: screenshot asciidoctor output]

Alternative to putting the sentence in an attribute: assuming that each chapter is described in a separate file, you can use an include statement that only includes the first line of the file for the table using `include::filename.txt[lines=1]`, and later include the full file inside the document. See [Include By Line Ranges in the Asciidoctor documentation](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#by-line-ranges) for details (you can also use tags to specify the contents for the table).

Comment: The first solution works fine except the text replaced for `<<link-1>>` is `[link-a]` with an underscore and not `R1`. However, it works as a link but I also get a warning while generating PDF as `asciidoctor: WARNING: invalid reference: link-a`.  
Versions used:  ```Asciidoctor PDF 1.5.0.alpha.16 using Asciidoctor 1.5.8  
Runtime Environment (ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]) (lc:UTF-8 fs:UTF-8 in:UTF-8 ex:UTF-8)```

Comment: @Anup - I've added the exact versions in the post. Both Asciidoctor 2.0.10 and Asciidoctor PDF 1.5.0.beta.1 don't show any warning or broken link.

Answer (score 2):

What @ahus1 said.

Or, if you can convert your counter lines into section titles, then it's easy:

```
= Document

[cols="a"]
|===
| <<first>>
| <<second>>
| <<third>>
|===

...

[[first]]
== R{counter:recom}: sentence 1

...

[[second]]
== R{counter:recom}: sentence 2

...

[[third]]
== R{counter:recom}: sentence 3

...


End
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about it but I have got sections already and a TOC which lists them. Thanks for the suggestion.